# CardView Layouts overlapping

Tags: android, layout

I have two cards views, I want to place one above the other but the end result is that they are placed on top of each other:

[image]

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/entryTypeCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/entryChoiceSpinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/currencySpinnerLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/currencyTypeCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/currencyChoiceSpinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/personNameTextField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign some id to first `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/first_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

and then used

```
android:layout_below="@+id/first_layout"
```

to second layout.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll never understand layouts and their attributes :(